# Return category posts with WP_Query

Tags: categories, wp-query

I have a some categories and want to get the posts with those categories:

```
$temp = $wp_query; // assign ordinal query to temp variable for later use  
$wp_query = null;

$wp_query = new WP_Query('cat=85'); 
if($wp_query->have_posts()) {   
    ...
}
```

But it is not entering in the `if` condition. The category with `id=85` exists and some posts are using it. So I don't understand why it is not returning any post.

Any idea. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you are doing. This will work with a valid ID with ___posts___ assigned to it. Are you trying to get posts from a CPT, perhaps?

Comment: @s_ha_dum - Sorry, CPT?

Comment: [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types)

Comment: @s_ha_dum - Oh! Yes. This is the problem. But I want to get all custom posts. Any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `WP_Query` will return only the `post` post type. To retrieve other post types, you need to add a `post_type` argument. Using `any` will return results from all public, registered post types.

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'cat' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'any'
  )
); 
var_dump($my_query->request); // debug; allows you to see the SQL
if($my_query->have_posts()) {   
  // ..
}
```

If you only want a particular post type, just use the post type's slug, or you can use an array of post type slugs to get returns from multiple particular post types.

Also, there is rarely a good reason to clobber `$wp_query`, even if you save it to put it back later.

Comment: Of course! Thank you. I'm using an Ajax call, this is why the `$wp_query`.